# Unable to view API Connect Cloud Foundry page

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, apiconnect

I have been given access to the an IBM Public Cloud (Dallas) 'Organization' and an API Connect Cloud Foundry resource (say, apic-dev). However, when I access the apic-dev resource from the 'Resource List', I see a [blank page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEawp.png). I've tried all browsers - chrome, firefox and safari. I am able to access all other resource types. This occurs only with 'API Connect' offering resource type. I have also confirmed that I've been given all user access needed by the administrator.

To verify if this is an access issue, I tried creating my own API Connect Cloud Foundry resource in my own IBM Cloud Organization, and got the exact same [blank page behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp3U4.png).

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Open a ticket with IBM Cloud Support.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open a private window in your browser or delete all the cookies.
I had the same problem and I always open the API Manager in a private window.